# Insert a array in a row in google app script

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to write in a cell of sheet an array that is inside an object

This is my gs code :

```
function sendText(data){

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1isl9CFp4lllCoKNzbYWIE3QHPkj6NekY3l_nm20MVF8").getActiveSheet();
 sheet.appendRow([null ,null ,null ,data.budgetName ,data.budgetDeadline ,data.budgetPayment ,data.budgetUrgency ,data.budgetArea ,data.budgetCurrency ,data.budgetTime ,data.budgetEmail ]);
return "succes!";
}
```

For example, With this variable inside the object I have no problem because it is not an array

```
    budgetName: e.target["name-budget"].value,
```

but if inside the object I pass an array, when it writes it to the array it writes something similar to this

[Cell view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgNOC.png)

What can I do so that the array that I send inside the object is shown in the cell?
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

#### How about

```
(data.budgetName.length > 0) ? data.budgetName.join(', '): data.budgetName
```